# How to insert additional content to page header from viewpage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc platform. I'm developing with razor template engine in mvc 3. I've created a layout page for all view pages but in some cases I need different page headers for different view pages. For example I have to insert additional script elements to page header to validate data in form pages.

I want to know is there any way to add html element to layout page's header from view page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could define a section in the head part of the master page:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts")
</head>
```

and in the view define this section:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="someplugin.js"></script>
}
```

You also have the possibility to test if a section is defined:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("mysection")) { 
    @RenderSection("mysection")
} 
else {
    <div>some default content</div>
}
```